# How can I read a single XML node by it's attribute?

Tags: c#, xml, database

My XML is built like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Pages>

    <Page id="1" title="myTitle">
        Content
    </Page>

    <Page id="2" title="myTitle2">
        Content2
    </Page>

</Pages>
```

How can I get the content by ID in C# code?

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich, +1 - but I think I've got it - I think the XML is a 'database'

Comment: @AndrasZoltan Yes it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use LINQ to XML and something like:

```
var document = XDocument.Load(...);
var page = document.Descendants("Page")
                   .Where(x => (int) x.Attribute("id") == id)
                   .FirstOrDefault();
```

Now `page` will be the first `XElement` with the given `id`, or null if it's not found.

Answer (score 5):

You could load it into XmlDocument and then call:

```
xmldocument.SelectSingleNode("/Pages/Page[Id = '1']")
```